# How to render JSP Page in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, backbone.js

I have created a backbone project, all the html's are now converted into jsp pages.

I am able to load the page if I am using the corresponding page jsp name in the URL.

For Example

`localhost:8080/abc/index.jsp || localhost:8080/abc/landing.jsp`

But the problem am facing is if I have a internal page routing, for example like

Consider a login page, which has forgot password link, if i click on that it should redirect to the forgot password page which is not happening.

For navigation am using `window.location.pathname = "/abc/landing.jsp"`

Manually am doing like this, is there a proper way to achieve with jsp pages navigation. Please help.

Code:
forgotpassword.jsp:

```
<input type="hidden" value="forgotPassword">
<div id="fp"></div>
```

based on the input hidden parameter, am deciding which new needs to be rendered.
and the formation of url is `http://localhost.abc.com:8080/test/forgotpassword.jsp`

Here is my router logic:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) {

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '*': 'default'
        },
    });

    var initialize = function() {
        var apRouter = new AppRouter;
        apRouter.on('route:default', function() {
            if ($('input').val == "fp") {
                require(['forgotpasswordView'], function(ForgotPswrd) {
                    var fpwrd = new ForgotPswrd();
                    fpwrd.render();
                });
                else {
                    require(['indexView'], function(IndexView) {
                        var iView = new IndexView();
                        iView.render();
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        Backbone.history.start();
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

So If i manually hit the URL appending corresponding jsp names like

```
http://localhost.abc.com:8080/test/forgotpassword.jsp or 

http://localhost.abc.com:8080/test/index.jsp
```

Then pages are loading and working fine. But If am calling another view from one view to another view then it is failing.

Like landing.html:

```
<button id="goTo"> Go to Next View </button>
```

Landing View JS:

```
events : "click#goTo : goTo"

goTo : function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault();
   Backbone.history.navigate('/',true);
}
```

Now the forgot password page needs to load but the url is not changing just appending hash to the previous url what ever is there.

Kindly help.

Comment: Like what? What is the question?

Comment: @ROmanc: I want to load the jsp page, once i click on forgot password.

Comment: Please post the code with jsp page that has a forgot password.

Comment: @RomanC: Code added please help me

Comment: @M-S normal `#` based routing is meant for single page apps... maybe you could use push state or something... I never used it. So you're loading all the scripts over and over again in different pages... Do you think there's any benefit from using stuff like require here...

Answer (score 0):

Backbone relies on router to make navigation possible.So if you have a route defined in the backbone route you can navigate to it by calling the route directly using the backbone route object.In your case you can create a route for the password forgotten link and load the template or view in the function def for that route .Trigger the ROUTE 'ON CLICK'.Eg :

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '*': 'default',
        '/forgotpassword' : 'forgotPass' 
    },
});

var appRoute = new AppRouter;

forgotPass() {
// load the view here
}

$('#button').on('click',function() {
  appRoute.navigate('/forgotpassword',true);
});
```

Please note that **you cannot load a jsp page as such through backbone js as the jsp files needs to be transpiled before rendering html** which cannot be done at client side. So you option is to ***use a templating engine like handlebar js and render the view using handlebar templates*** wherever necessary.